# Unity - Randomly generated Worms like destrucible terrain advice

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting, mesh, collider

I've been looking online for some guidelines for this and have had no luck.
I'm having issues with the destructible part of my terrain.
I currently have a script which fills in a 2d array with 1's and 0's and then continues to create a mesh and collider from this array.
The trouble I'm having is that I have no idea how to detect a part of the mesh which was hit with an explosion and then almost cut the explosion from the mesh. I'm struggling to find any hints on how to modify a runtime generated mesh.

All I've been seeing online so far are 3rd party assets, but I'd like to avoid using assets as much as possible.

I'm not asking for someone to provide me with a solution, rather, point me in the right direction.

I'm sorry if this explanation was lacking, but in short, is it possible to modify a mesh at runtime and if so, how?

Comment: My go-to would be to regenerate the mesh any time the underlying array changes.

Comment: yes: https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/projects/procedural-cave-generation-tutorial/creating-meshes